# Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a log-in section, which should take an email id/phone number and password, and check the database. As simple as it should be, I'm getting a TypeError that states "string is not a function" on the line -

```
if ($e_check!=0) {
```

of the following code:

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    include_once("db_conx.php");
    $u = $_POST["username"];
    $p1 = $_POST["password"];
    $p = md5($p1);
    if ($u!=""){
        if (is_numeric($u)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone='$u' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1"; //check against phone numbers
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             $result = mysqli_result($query);
        $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);


            //var_dump($e_check);
             if ($e_check != 0) {
                echo "Success!";
                exit();
            }
            else {
                echo "Password is incorrect";
                exit();
            } 
        }

        else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$u' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1"; //check against email
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             $result = mysqli_result($query);
        $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            var_dump($e_check);
             if ($e_check != 0) {
                echo "Success!";
                exit();
            }
            else {
                echo "Password is incorrect";
                exit();
            } 

        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sign In</title>

<script src="ajax.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function login(){
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value();
    var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value();
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    if (username=="" || password == "") {
        status.innerHTML = "Email/Phone or Password is missing";
    }

    else {
        status.innerHTML = "Please wait...";
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index2.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "Success!"){ ///returned from php file
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

                }
                else {
                    //alert("Logged in");
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }
       ajax.send("username="+username+"&password="+password); //shoots variable to php 

    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageRight">
    <form id="sign-up" onSubmit="return false;">
        Email/Phone: <input type="text" id="username" >
        Password: <input type="password" id="pwd">
        <button id="signin" onClick="login()" style="background-color:#9C092B; color: white; padding: 9px 15px">Sign In </button><br>
        <span id="status" style="color: red"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that the variable e_check doesn't retrieve the right return-type, but I can't see why that's happening. Is there a better way to check if the query is a success, or can you suggest any modifications to the existing code which could remove this error? I'm a newbie to PHP and I apologize if this is a stupid question. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: I don't think PHP reports error as TypeErorr

Comment: What's it say if you `var_dump($e_check);`?

Comment: @TomHart, it's strange, but I'm getting the error on var_dump, now. *frustrated* :/

Comment: How are you invoking this piece of PHP code? It's JavaScript that reports type error, not PHP.

Comment: @N.B. - I guess you're right, the error is sticking to the particular "line 12", so it might be something to do with JavaScript. Failing to understand why, because it's pointing to my PHP code. I've added the whole code, any ideas?

Comment: Use your browsers' developer tools, find the AJAX request > check what it says for the message content. Then you can see what really happens.

Comment: @N.B. yeah I am using the console on Chrome, that's the only thing I get "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
```

not

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value();
var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value();
```

Comment: Omg I'm so embarrassed. THANK YOU! This solved the problem.

Comment: Don't mind. You may just be tired.

Comment: Debugging is mind-boggling, especially when it's your own code. Could you please tell me why the console was pointing to the wrong line? Its error was pointing to the PHP section whereas the error was being caused by JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using Chrome's console to debug? Php's error message should be in php_error.log or apache's error_log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spaces in the statement (you have this in both conditions of your if statement), it is just bad form -

```
if ($e_check != 0) {
```

However, this is not likely your problem as others have pointed out. a TypeError issue is one of JavaScript, not PHP. The statement that you have created will work in PHP.

Comment: Wrong, spaces are optional.

Comment: I won't downvote you, but what you wrote isn't true. Try to run your example to see. I suggest removing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jay but that didn't help.

Comment: If I run the example I get a TypeError warning. EDIT: but I am not able to run this in the same context as the OP, I am just setting `$e_check`.

Comment: Sry, nope. I checked this on my local instance - same results. I think, you mean the following: if($e_check=!$0) - this is important with space. Athorwise not.

Comment: Just a quick question - are you answering from the POV of PHP code or JavaScript code? It is true that PHP doesn't return TypeError - JS does. The issue is that question is about PHP (kudos for deducing that JS reports the issue). You should probably make it more clear about the context of the language you're answering for.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I did a couple of more tests and I see that what you say is true - the spaces are optional. I do find that the lack of spaces is bad form though. (I'm still getting a TypeError warning with the OP's statement, without being able to replicate the rest of his situation.)

Comment: * *facepalm* * Thanks for pointing that out @N.B. - not enough coffee this morning.

Answer (score 0):

You need a result, to get a num_row count. Use this:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone='$u' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1"; //check against phone numbers
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $result = mysqli_result($query);
        $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Still not helping. Wait, I'm editing and uploading my entire code, I think there might be an issue in something else. :/